# Jenkins pipeline plugin - Jenkins as code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Just trying to understand the pipeline as code along with pipeline plugin in jenkins 2.0. I know the advantage of that , but my question is around  the deployment workflow in any company, for example , we can deploy to dev , qa , prod , whenever we want, Now if I go with the pipeline plugin , is like with every commit it will run the whole pipeline , commit , tests , deploy dev , qa , prod, it will be deploying always the latest commit. Is there any way to run a manual trigger to deploy any version of my code and don't the latest?
Is pipeline plugin a replacement of build pipeline view?

Comment: Just because you _can_ do everything in a single pipeline doesn't mean you _have to_ do everything in a single pipeline. My apps go through several different pipelines between dev and prod. I think the point of pipelines is to provide flexibility, as opposed to putting your processes on rails.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a job manually. Just uncheck all conditions in the "build triggers" part of the job configuration.

Then, you can create multiple job.
For exemple, the first one runs tests.
The second deploy to dev, and run functionnal test / test database schemas evolutions.
The third, deploy to QA...

Any job can be trigerred by another job, so Jenkins can automatically run the second job only if the first succeded.

Comment: yes I know that , I refer specifically to pipeline-plugin in jenkins 2.0 , it is running some kind of stage , but I don't have the option of manually trigger a stage. or restart a stage.

Comment: So the comment of @Jacob helps I think.